# POST variable error

Tags: javascript, php, html, post

Good day, i need past variable in post to other file

```
  }
        $.ajax({
            url: 'emps.php',
            type: 'POST', // GET or POST
             data: {"sucursal":$("#suc").val()},
            success: function(data) { // data is the response from your php script
                // This function is called if your AJAX query was successful
              alert(data);
            },
            error: function() {
                // This callback is called if your AJAX query has failed
                alert("Errors!");
            }
        });
}
```

code variable

```
<tr>
    <td class="col1"><label for="pat">Sucursal:</label></td>
    <td class="col2">
        <input type="text" name="suc" id="suc"  class="medium" readonly="true" style="width: 200px;"size="40" maxlength="200" onChange="javascript:this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();" />
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="sbm" name="sbm" value="Buscar" onclick="llenaSucursales()" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

Error image is :

[image]

whats its a problem?

I await your help and I started reading and search and can not find the error

Comment: Rather than just alerting a string on error, use arguments to figure out what exactly is going wrong.

`error(xHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert(errorThrown) }`

Comment: Have you used the developer tools in your web browser? They are a huge help in situations like this. Turn it on, head to the console, and network tabs, and watch what happens when you click or submit things. Also, as Kurt said... add more variable output, and debug lines to figure out an issue easier.

Comment: You error is happening in "emps.php". So either devug your php code, or alert the error thrown from the ajax response as @Kurt said

Answer (score 2):

You should have a look at the [jQuery documentation for $.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to understand what you may use to react on errors in your AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'emps.php',
  type: 'POST', // GET or POST
  data: {"sucursal":$("#suc").val()},
  success: function(data) { // data is the response from your php script
    // This function is called if your AJAX query was successful
    alert(data);
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, status, errorThrown) {
    // This callback is called if your AJAX query has failed
    alert('Got the error ' + errorThrown + ' with status ' +status);
  }
});
```

I would also recommend to open up the Developer Tools (F12 in most browsers) and check the "Network tab" to see the responses of AJAX calls.

*Not related to your question:*

In the future please take more care when writing your post. Remove unnecessary blank lines, don't post code with errors (just concentrate on the important parts of what you post) - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The error was that I was missing "/" the address of the file, Thanks, then I leave the code

```
function empleados(){

 if($("#suc").val()=='')
    {
        alert('Elige una sucursal');
        return false;
    }
        $.ajax({
            url: '/emps.php',
            type: 'POST', // GET or POST
             data: {"suc":$("#suc").val()},
            success: function(data) { // data is the response from your php script
                // This function is called if your AJAX query was successful
              alert(data);
            },
            error: function() {  
                // This callback is called if your AJAX query has failed
                alert("Errors!");

            }
        });
}
```

Comment: If that solved your answer, please accept it as solution so the question does not remain open. If one of the comments helped you solve your problem, please upvote. And as stated below in my answer, please take more care in writing your question the next you need help.